# overlaping contents inside ul, ul's size which is too small

Tags: html, css

i keep wondering why the ul size is too small while the contents inside that ul just overlaps, i wanted the height to be automatically resized for it to be responsive and align in each borders top and bottom, but adding fixed height like let say 500px but when i resize the browser, the contents just overlaps and not aligned in borders, any ideas?

here's my fiddle:
jsfiddle.net/D9pKb/

Comment: You get a notice saying not to post *just* a link to JSFiddle when posting a question, and instead of doing what it asks and posting some of your code up here you've removed the `http://` from the link, which is plain silly.

Comment: It’s because you floated the LI. https://www.google.com/search?q=containing+floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to `ul#textwrap`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/D9pKb/1/)**

```
ul#textwrap {
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:5% 6% 5% 6%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-top:2px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom:2px solid #aaa;
    overflow:auto;
}
```